# Tons of gradle error "Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name" when building for Google Glass

Tags: android, android-appcompat, google-glass

I'm trying to make an app for Google Glass. But when I tried to sync the gradle, it showed me 200-ish errors like this (kind of a lot so I put it on pastebin):

```
https://pastebin.com/5LJXEy1w
```

In short, those errors are of the type "Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name" from a lot of intermediate files. This is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'prebuilt-libs'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19"
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.zeroexperiencestudio.glassqr"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.2'
}
```

Why is this happening? And how do I fix this?

And this is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.zeroexperiencestudio.glassqr">

    <application
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivityTest"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
        >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.glass.VoiceTrigger"
                android:resource="@xml/voice" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `android:theme` from `AndroidManifest.xml` file if you are using.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any `android:theme` in my manifest and use the default theme for Google Glass. Thanks anyway.